# Is the pair $(\{0,4,8,12\},+_{16})$ consist a Group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is the pair $(\{0,4,8,12\},+_{16})$ consist a Group?

I think  $\{0,4,8,12\}$ is written as  $\{[0],[4],[8],[12]\}$, where

$
[a]=\{x\in{Z}:x=a+n.k,k\in{Z}\}
$

I don't understand how this is a group because from what I know is that if

$A,B\in{Z}$, and $A+B\in{Z}$, then $(Z,+)$ is a group

but for $(\{0,4,8,12\},+_{16})$ I don't understand how I could do that?

Comment: You'll have to provide more context for an answer to the second part.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It's a pair consisting of a set and a binary operation.

Comment: @Ramsus ...right. Comment redacted.

Comment: What's $+_{16}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Notice that $\langle [4]\rangle= \{[0],[4],[8],[12]\} \subseteq \frac{\mathbb Z}{16 \mathbb Z}$.

- $h_1 +_{16} h_2 \in \{[0],[4],[8],[12]\}, \forall h_1, h_2 \in \{[0],[4],[8],[12]\}$
- $h^{-1} \in \{[0],[4],[8],[12]\}, \forall h \in \{[0],[4],[8],[12]\}$

Comment: but, if $h_1=[8]$ and $h_2=[12]$ then $h_1+h_2=[20]\not\in{ \{[0],[4],[8],[12]\}}$

Comment: Notice that $[20] = [4]$. Do you know modular arithmetic?

Comment: No, I am really new to this!, How is $[20]=[4]$?

Comment: Okay, here is a heads up. Take any integer number, say $20 \in \mathbb Z$ and divide it by $16$, then $$20 = 16 \dot \, 1 + 4 $$ the remainder is $4$ and that is a class in $\mathbb Z / 16\mathbb Z$ represented by $[4]$ and we say that $[20] = [4]$. That is, you define an equivalence relation $$a \sim b \iff 16|(b - a)$$ and get a partition of $\mathbb Z$. In other words we have $$\mathbb Z /16 \mathbb Z = \{[0],[1],[2],\ldots, [15]\}$$

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful, just one more so I can make sure I understand, your saying that $[a]=[b]$, if 16 is divisible by $(b-a)$, and if $h_1=[4]$ then is $h_{1}^{-1}=[-4]$

Comment: Elements are in the same equivalence class if that happens. Yes.

Comment: Aaron Maroja, do you have any good references I can  read about this subject?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22695/discussion-between-aaron-maroja-and-435145).

Answer (score 1):

A best way to show a finite set together with a binary operation is really a group is  drawing its **Cayley table**. Here is a Cayley table for your problem

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 \oplus_{16}& 0 & 4&8&12 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 4 & 8&12 \\ \hline
4 & 4 & 8 & 12&0 \\ \hline
8 & 8 & 12& 0&4 \\ \hline
12 & 12 &0& 4&8 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

As you can see, it is simple to verify the four group axioms from this perspective.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, you can just check all the axioms.

2) You can consider the elements of your group as equivalences classes modulo 16 in the integers $\mathbb Z$. Your group is then $4\mathbb Z/16\mathbb Z$.

[This answer appeared before the edit of the original post.]